# Get all users last_name which have same first_name

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to receive an object which includes all last_names of users with the same first_name from the Wordpress usermeta table. The first_name to search for is given.
 i.e. John Miller, John Doe and John Appleseed are registered users on my Wordpress page. I want to get an object including Miller, Doe and Appleseed.

I tried the following query, but its only returns one last_name as caused by LIMIT 1

```
SELECT `meta_value`
FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE `user_id` = (
    SELECT `user_id`
    FROM `wp_usermeta`
    WHERE `meta_value` LIKE 'John' AND
          `meta_key` = 'first_name'
    LIMIT 1
) AND `meta_key` = 'last_name';
```

How do I have to modify this query to receive all user last_names?

Comment: just change the `where user_id = (...` to `where user_id in (...` and remove the `limit 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the `where user_id = (...` to `where user_id in (...` and remove the `limit 1`

```
SELECT `meta_value`
FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE `user_id` in (
    SELECT `user_id`
    FROM `wp_usermeta`
    WHERE `meta_value` LIKE 'John' AND
          `meta_key` = 'first_name' 
) AND `meta_key` = 'last_name';
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest comparing the `EXPLAIN` output from this query to the one in my answer; depending on the version of MySQL you use, one query may perform better than the other.

Comment: @cdhowie - there's a couple of ways to write the query.  I just provided the one with the least amount of modifications to the original query.  [Both queries in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/201e7/1), which shows the explain plans.  Let's pretend the table is ridiculously huge... which would take longer?  The join or the subquery?  The `like` could definitely add some time.

Comment: After [adding indexes](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9a16/1), it appears that my query will be faster because this query has a dependent subquery while mine does not.  However, for small data sets both should perform well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Join the table to itself to relate the first name to the last name, then apply a simple equality `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    f.user_id,
    f.meta_value AS first_name,
    l.meta_value AS last_name
FROM wp_usermeta f
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta l
    ON f.user_id = l.user_id AND
       f.meta_key = 'first_name' AND
       l.meta_key = 'last_name'
WHERE f.meta_value = 'John';
```

Example execution in PostgreSQL (but the query should also work in MySQL):

```
$ WITH wp_usermeta (user_id, meta_key, meta_value) AS (VALUES
    (1, 'first_name', 'John'),
    (1, 'last_name', 'Miller'),
    (2, 'first_name', 'John'),
    (2, 'last_name', 'Doe'),
    (3, 'first_name', 'John'),
    (3, 'last_name', 'Appleseed'),
    (4, 'first_name', 'Bob'),
    (4, 'last_name', 'Doe')
)
SELECT
    f.user_id,
    f.meta_value AS first_name,
    l.meta_value AS last_name
FROM wp_usermeta f
INNER JOIN wp_usermeta l
    ON f.user_id = l.user_id AND
       f.meta_key = 'first_name' AND
       l.meta_key = 'last_name'
WHERE f.meta_value = 'John';

 user_id | first_name | last_name
---------+------------+-----------
       1 | John       | Miller
       2 | John       | Doe
       3 | John       | Appleseed
(3 rows)
```